# Neural network activation functions for continuous outcomes

Tags: neural-networks, activation-function

I understand we should always scale/normalize the variables in ANN models (correct me if I am wrong), but still, I was wondering if certain activation functions, like sigmoid, can be used when the output neuron of a neural network is a continous, not scaled/normalized variable? And if not, would it change if the variable had been normalized?

In those lines, I suppose there would be no issues with using activation functions like softplus and ReLU (in addition to linear) if the output neuron is a continous, not scaled/normalized variable, right?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Softplus and ReLU as activations for output layers won’t work very well when the outcome has negative values! Likewise sigmoid for values not in [0,1].

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't considering negative values when I asked the question, but good point---I will keep that in mind!

Comment: What does being continuous have to do with being scaled to $[0,1]?$ Do you just mean a numerical outcome instead of a category?

Comment: Yes, numerical.

Comment: are you talking about the output layer or latent layers?

Comment: The output layer.

Comment: @Sycorax I would also say that ReLU is not a good choice since has 0 gradient, so no gradient will be propagated no matter which loss function he uses